# Correct use of time matches or time match

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the below sentence is correct?

Coincidencely, From past 2 -3 days me and my friend leave office at same time and meet at bus stop at same time. So curiosly I want to ask him ......

a) Why our time always matches?

Or

b) Why our time always match?

Comment: Neither one of those sentences is correctly formed. Questions typically follow an inverted verb-subject pattern, e.g. _Why do you, How is he, Can they..._

Comment: I can't quite follow the logic of of this stream of thought. If your leaving office at the same time is a coincidence, why are you asking your friend about it? Let's ignore that part and look at grammar alone. Your lead-up sentence should be: "Coincidentally, for the past two or three days, my friend and I leave office at the same time, and end up meeting at the bus stop. So, I was curious to ask him...". The section you are asking about should be "... why our times always match." This would be grammatically sound, but I would not use this wording myself.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the time you leave the office and the time that your friend leaves the office, and are wondering why these two **times** match: note the plural. As an affirmative statement, you would therefore say

> Our times always match.

When you make a question, you have to invert the subject and the auxiliary verb. If there is no auxiliary word, you add **do** as an auxiliary verb, then invert it.

> Our times do always match - *add **do** as an auxiliary verb*
>   Why do our times always match? - *invert subject and auxiliary*

The correct sentence is therefore

> Why do our times always match?